# Nginx error log won't read variable

Tags: nginx

In my vhost I have:

```
root   /var/www/$server_name/public_html;
index  index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/$server_name.error.log debug;
```

For the root and the access log the `$server_name` work. It does not work for the error log.

[image]

I see it's set by root instead of pi (I use *pi* instead of *data-www*)
How do I fix this?

*nginx/1.13.5*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know variables are still not allowed in `error_log` even though you can use them in `access_log` (as your screenshot reveals properly working in your scenario).

Besides that, you should almost always use `$host` as it is the only guaranteed variable to say something sensible regardless of the user-agent's behavior.

You can check the difference between $host and $server_name on [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

- `$host`: in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request.
- `$server_name`: name of the server *which accepted* a request. It contains the `server_name` of the virtual host which processed the request, as it was defined in the nginx configuration. If a server contains multiple server_names, only the first one will be present in this variable.

As you have to account for all the possible things that a user-agent may do then forming an HTTP request (ancient HTTP/1.0 requests and modern badly-written software can happen all the time), you should consider using only the `$host` variable for your intended purpose.

Worth mentioning that `access_log` [is handled](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) by `ngx_http_log_module`, while error_log [is handled](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html?&_ga=2.84571931.349931258.1509398879-1853019796.1509398879#error_log) a little bit differently as a `ngx_core_module`.

Comment: Thanks for the difference of `$host`. For my setup I'd like `$server_name` As each vhost is ` domain +www. and this way I'll never have separate logs for www.